# Connect an RJ45 (Ethernet) cable to RJ11 jack (telephone)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have a landline telephone jack in my room that I wish to get an adapter for that allows me to use the Ethernet port on my computer (what is the name of this adapter?).

However the house I live in has a router connected downstairs hooked up to a telephone line. My question is can I get this adapter (whatever it's called) and use Ethernet in my room using the telephone line or will it disrupt the house router? Will I have to wire my Ethernet to the router to use upstairs in my room?

Comment: Your question is way too vague to provide a good answer to. Note that Ethernet is a standard, not a physical thing. Do you mean Ethernet *cable*? Correct your question to clarify as such if that is the case. Also, elaborate on what your router is doing connected to a telephone line. Do you have DSL? And your question may be easier to answer if you provide a goal (what you're trying to achieve). You've asked some questions but there may be a better option.

Comment: Vague. Vague. Vague! Suppose there is such a thing as RJ45 to RJ11 adapter. (Not that I ever heard of.) To where are you planning to connect with it? A network outside your home or just your home?

Comment: This is an XY question. You need to ask us for help solving your problem, not help implementing what you think is the solution. Rather than asking about some kind of imaginary adapter that probably doesn't exist, ask us how you could best connect your computer to the existing network. Is the router wireless? Are you in its range? Is powerline Ethernet a good solution for you? What speeds do you require? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking about something like a powerline-adapter. Powerline-adaptor needs an electric socket to send the encrypted data frequencies over the current-wire-net. In your case from an electric socket next to your router to your room upstairs.

It's a problem to do it with a telephone-line since (I imagine) the telephone cable have only 2 wires, but you need at least 4 wires for Ethernet cat 1-5 and 8 wires for cat 5-7. And you should know where the cable of the telephone socket upstairs, ends. In the case the telephone wire have 4 and more wires and the wire is directly connected to the one downstairs, you would need a crimping tool with Ethernet-LAN connectors. As advise, the telephone wire and cable is usually not built to use for LAN, because of some electromagnetic differences.

[examples](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=powerline%20adapter)

Comment: There's also similar phoneline-based networking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePNA

Answer (score 0):

landline uses 2 to 4 wires in the cable for an outlet while Ethernet uses 6 to 8 (always recommended 8).
Sometimes in newer homes/offices builders will use Cat5e cable (ethernet) for a landline.  If this is the case a new adapter can be put on each end other cable for this purpose if the builder did not use one cable for multiple landlines (also common).
running a new cable is the best solution.  or using dialup (not a good option)

Comment: Cat5e is not used for a landline. You may be referring to VoIP.

Comment: And dial-up cannot be used with a router either. This answer is all wrong.

Comment: @InterLinked It's not all that uncommon these days to use Cat5e for landline telephone links. There's no significant cost difference and it permits the lines to later be used for a network if the landline is abandoned. And, as the answer correctly points out, if really all he has is a landline jack he can't rewire, all he can use it for is dialup, which would suck. The answer is entirely correct, but probably useless to the OP because the OP has asked an XY question.

Comment: @InterLinked As i attempted to point out in my answer Cat5e is used is some newer homes and offices entirely based on the contractor.  I find both homes and offices with Cat5e cabling being used 1 cable for 1-4 landline ports varying on the need at that time or simply contractor preference.   Because its not likely it is not Cat5e cable i recommended pulling a new cable, which would provide the correct cable and the ability to know the cable has no hidden defects such as a bad kink halfway through the pull.  and as a wired alternative Using the landline(not router) dialup.  Thank you David.